# Getting fb.me URL

Tags: facebook, url, hyperlink, short

How do I go about either making, or retrieving facebook short url's (fb.me) from a page, profile, event etc? I want to update my url shortener site - but if the user links to a facebook page I want to just return a fb.me link instead. Does facebook make their short urls on the fly, or does each page automatically already have one?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Facebook uses [Bit.ly](http://bit.ly/)'s services to shorten links from their site. While pages that have a username turns into "`fb.me/<username>`", other links associated with Facebook turns into "`on.fb.me/*****`". To you use the on.fb.me service, just use your Bit.ly account. Note that if you change the default link shortener on your Bit.ly account to j.mp from bit.ly this service won't work.

Comment: There is one significant change since 2011. `on.fb.me` is still powered by Bitly, however `fb.me` is operated internally by Facebook itself.

Comment: I guess that's expected. Where did you find this info, if you don't mind sharing? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use bit.ly api to create facebook short urls find the documentation here 
http://api.bitly.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to programmatically create these URLs, but the existing username space (www.facebook.com/something) works on fb.me also (e.g. http://fb.me/facebook )

Comment: That's just for usernames.

Comment: I did say that in my answer

Comment: Oh, you're right. I hoped they would support the whole namespace.